# How can I make a table with a fixed width, but not a fixed height?

Tags: html, html-table

I am having trouble make a jsfiddle that reproduces my problem, but I have one that demonstrates the basic layout I am dealing with.

http://jsfiddle.net/LurUM/4/

```
<div style="width: 73%; float: left;">
    <!-- table here -->
</div>
<div style="width: 23%; float: right;">
    <!-- sidebar here -->
</div>
```

I have a table on a page like this one, but it is not the correct width, it is much wider, colliding with the right side bar and going past it.  I tried setting the table's width to 100% and going to a fixed table-layout.  The width behaved exactly as I wanted it to, but then some of the texts in the cells of the table were spilling out and colliding with text in other columns.  What I want is for the cells to become taller and the text to go onto a new line instead of spilling over, but if I understand correctly the fixed layout is preventing this.

Am I understanding the situation correctly?  What's the solution?  And why did the table have so much extra width to begin with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<table style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td style="word-wrap: break-word">
LongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongWord
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The `word-wrap: break-word` property will wrap long words onto the next line and adjust words so that they don't break mid-word. When used in conjunction with `table-layout: fixed;` it will prevent the table bounds from overflowing.

Answer (score -1):

If there is other content that must remain aligned with your table then keep the divs, otherwise I would suggest using id names for the tables, and moving all styles to the applicable style sheet. Your tables will then be getting their width setting directly from css instead of overflowing a parent container. I would also suggest that you use only one float, which ever is topmost on your page. This will keep the html cleaner i.e. easier to read and debug.

```
<div class="leftSide">
   <table>html</table>
   <p>other stuff that must be aligned with table</p>
</div>
<table id="rightTable">table that will float around other content</table>
<div>other content will continue to float until space is used up</div>

CSS
.leftSide {float: left; width: 40%; margin-right 20px; }
.leftSide table {width: 90%; }
.leftSide p {other css}
```

The html is easier to read this way, and specificity is used to drill down to the elements within the div, the table will be 90 percent of the width of its parent div and will no longer overflow the container (unless you put some giant image in there). Other CSS can be added including the  word-wrap and break-word mentioned in other answers.
w3 has the definitive answers for CSS specificity and other inheritance issues like the one your facing http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/